# Angular JS render list with finite elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list with finite elements around 30-40 elements but on an average on screen the number of elements rendered is 4-7. I am using ng-repeat to render this list. Rendering of each element is very expensive I want to render elements only present in viewport.

Virtual scroll is not a solution for me as height of elements can be different, but I don't have infinite elements either. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try angular-vs-repeat (https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat, http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=6) - it can deal with elements with different height. but you need a way to calculate height of not visible elements.

Comment: @user1017860 Did you tried my solution? Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't add some code I'll try to imagine what you want.

In you're case I'd use something like `ngInfiniteScroll`.

As you can see in the demo link:
https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html

```
$scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      $scope.images.push(last + i);
    }
  };
```

As you can see this is example includes a finite array or items and therefore it's easy for you to set the checkpoints.

Now I hope this solves your problem. Otherwise please share your code base.

Cheers

Comment: This does not solve my problem as height of my elements is not same. I have mentioned the same in the question too.